# Is a drop in Domain Authority (DA) for a website & it's competitor unusual?

Tags: seo

I monitor the DA of a businesses website and 5 of their top local competitors. Competition level reaches across the entire US but some are within the same state.

Moz sends me a weekly report of DA changes and then I verify those changes with other tools to make sure the reporting is as accurate as possible.

This week something happened that I have never seen before. The site I'm watching and it's competitors all had a drop in DA. Each between 1-3 points.

Would there be a reason for the drop across the board or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this without knowing more about the situation.   The change could be due to a change in the tools you are monitoring.   A site that had been linking to your site and competitors could have been taken down.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't care to much about this. As Stephen said, this could very well be related to OSE. Perhaps they cleaned up their index and removed a bunch links. Don't be blinded by DA values in Moz. If you're going to watch any of these metrics, focus on the metrics from Majestic SEO's and Ahrefs. Their indexes are much larger than Moz's.

Comment: As Stephen said, hard to know without more details. For example, it might be the vertical you're in, too. Google releases algorithm updates regularly and no longer informs anyone about it. Remember when all public relations sites took a hit? A Google update may thus impact an entire vertical, or it's a possibility that most sites within certain industries use the same techniques (backlink schemes, certain kinds of ads) and Google targeted that technique with its latest release.

Answer (score 1):

A 1-3 point drop in the domain authority is nothing particularly concerning. The Moz domain authority score is a logarithmic score between 1 and 100 and is calculated based on a wide variety of metrics, many of which Moz doesn't outrightly specify, however based on some information that Moz does release it would appear to take into account data from competitor sites. A 1-3 point drop could simply be explained away by the publishing of a new domain that competes with your own.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Moz don't the infrastructure to track all backlinks for a website. It only finds only few link and Gives the authority.
And, After a period of time it will again adjust all its authorities by discovering new links to website. If it don't any new link or Drop of existing links it will decrease the site authority.